# 'DDLog.h' file not found

Tags: ios, cocoaasyncsocket, cocoalumberjack

I am trying to enable the logging inside `CocoaAsyncSocket` by doing the following inside `GCDAsyncSocket.m`:

```
#ifndef GCDAsyncSocketLoggingEnabled
#define GCDAsyncSocketLoggingEnabled 1
#endif
```

However, when I build the project I receive the following error:

[image]

What I am missing here?

Note: I am importing both `CocoaAsyncSocket` and `CocoaLumberjack` inside my Swift project using Cocoapods as following:

```
def shared
  pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'
  pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
end

target 'Project' do
  shared

  target 'MyFrameworkTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    shared
  end
end

target 'MyFramework' do
  shared
end

target 'MyFrameworkTests' do
  shared
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a lot of issues, including [this](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/issues/614), and didn't seem to find a clear answer.

My experience tells me that the header file is not found, meaning the file does not exist.

#### There are two ways:

**1. Manually integrate `CocoaLumberjack`, `CocoaAsyncSocket`**

You can download [source code](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) directly, where the `Source` folder contains the information you want.

**2.[`Cocoapods Specs`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html)**

The first method I tested, it worked.
The second method I am not familiar with, there is no test.

It should be noted that all libraries integrated by `Cocopods` are compiled separately and have no dependencies.

Comment: the importing error is inside `GCDAsyncSocket.m` not inside my Swift classes!

Comment: sorry，my miss. I updated the answer and hope to help you.